# How to retrieve information from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code to retrieve information from a database. It connect connects to the database, but when I try to display the information I don't see anything. I only get 
the dash lines. I think the problem is in the while loop, I just can not see where my mistake is. Can anyone help??

```
 $connection = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","root","xxxxxxxx");
        if (!$connection)
        {
        printf("Can't connect to MySQL Server.", mysqli_connect_error());

        }


    mysql_select_db('xxxxxx') or die ('Could not select database');
        echo 'You have been connected succesfully to your database';

        $query = "SELECT *FROM testing";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query fail:".mysql_error());


        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
        {
            echo $row['age']."--".$row['sex']."--".$row['id']."--".$row['country']."--".$row['sport']." ";
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Looking at the code it "should" work unless you're encountering an error or no results in your query. Is this an ajax loaded page you are calling from a parent page? if so you need to use the ajax result and set a div or element html.

Comment: Not is not an ajax loadedpage @Silvertiger

Comment: did you try a `var_dump($row)` to see what you really got from the query? remember that the array keys are case-sensitive. If you get the `--` as output, then your loop **IS** working, you're probably just accessing invalid/undefined array keys. If there were NO results, then the loop wouldn't run at all and you wouldn't even get the `--`.

Comment: I see you have your wildcard and FROM with no space, is that a typo and should be "* FROM" with the spaee added?

Comment: I did not try that @MarcB. I am new with php, so there are many stuff that I/m still learning

Comment: In these cases I do var_dump($result) to make sure that MySQL has in fact retrieved something. Using *FROM or * FROM, i.e. with or without space doesn't matter, I just checked it on my MySQL console and it returns results either way. But just in case you can try to put a space, maybe your version of MySQL does need a space.

Comment: The mysql functions you are using are depreciated and will "go away" soon. Best to switch to MySQLi or PDO. I use this one: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: I got the following when I do var_dump($result): resource(4) of type (mysql result)

Comment: @zeeshan I got the following when I do var_dump($result): resource(4) of type (mysql result)

Comment: Please try `var_dump($row)` instead, doing `var_dump($result)` is meaningless *(you should put this into the `while` loop to get the best results)*.

Comment: @PetrR. with var_dump($row) i got the following: bool(false)

Comment: There should be no semicolon (`;`) in this line: `while (...);`

Comment: @PetrR. thank you very much. It works now. I just have an extra question. How is the information stored in the array???. in this case, I have four rows. would every row correspond to an index in the array?

Comment: @user3648429 - I posted an answer with details about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysqli

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","admin","XXXXXX","test");
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `testing`";  

if(!$result = $db->query($query)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}

// echo $result->num_rows;  Uncomment to make sure there is data being ruturned

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['age']."--".$row['sex']."--".$row['id']."--".$row['country']."--".$row['sport']." ";   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the semicolon (`;`) after `while(...)`, so your final code will look like:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['age']."--".$row['sex']."--".$row['id']."--".$row['country']."--".$row['sport']." ";
}
```

---

Whatever is in your `while` loop *(between `{` and `}`)* will be called as many times as many  rows will return your query. For example, if your query will return 4 rows, then your code (`echo ...`) will be repeated 4 times. In the first run, variables `$row["age"]`, `$row["sex"]`, `$row["id"]` and `$row["country"]` will contain the results for the first row. On the second run, these variables will contain the results of the second row...

---

**Also, please, don't use the [`mysql_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) functions, they are [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) and will be removed in the future versions of PHP. Use [`MySQLi`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) instead.** See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/1935077) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, turns out my DB had no information in it, and one of my value names was incorrect.  Can you confirm there are valid values in your DB?